# select one input channel from stereo (or quad) group?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have a multi-channel USB input device (Behringer UMC 404HD) and, as you might expect, it has several different microphones on it.

For one particular purpose (Zoom, and similar, meetings) I would like to take my input from only one of the channels (i.e. the one microphone that's in front of me). I don't want the aural clutter of the input from the others.

Generally, I'm using the regular Ubuntu settings, which allows me to select the device in preference to the various other audio devices on this machine but doesn't let me do anything more specific than that.

I have also tried using pavucontrol, but that too doesn't seem to provide a means of selecting a single channel for a mono input.

Is there a way to do this that can be reconfigured easily?

TIA
Toby

Comment: Something like https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples#Remap_left_or_right_to_mono.

Comment: Looks like it @CL. I'll do some studying, thanks!